# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eq' of undefined from Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror

My site on http://housingtrustfundproject.org/housing-trust-fund-newsletter/
used to display a slider with featured articles--similar to the slider on the home page.  One day, it stops and I got this error on my console:

basic-jquery-slider.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eq' of undefinedA @ basic-jquery-slider.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ basic-jquery-slider.min.js:1

My hunch is the basis-jquery-slider.min.js, which is hosted on : http://housingtrustfundproject.org/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3

Any hints on where and how to troubleshoot this will be great.

Comment: And how do you debug it???

Comment: I used google chrome dev tool to look at the console.  That's the question I want to ask myself.

Comment: i see you are using jq 1.4.2. Have you try updating to more recent jQuery version? At first, you should try using jq 1.8 (>1.9 has major changes)

Comment: Hi the jquery is already 1.8.2 already.  I think the issue is the basic-jquery-slider.min.js file.  I just don't see the connection on how this file create a TypeError that breaks our code, since this is not a cdn but hosted.

Comment: Ok i see you are including jQuery twice, 1.4.2 and 1.8.2. Replace 1.4.2 include by 1.8.2 and remove your own 1.8.2 include